# Fixed width across different devices

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I am using React & styled-components

I was wondering if anyone knows how to keep a fixed width across different devices. Below I have a design example where it crops the width of an image without losing quality.

How can I achieve this? Can anyone provide an example?

[image]

Comment: do you want your picture to keep the same width on all different devices or to be responsive but maintain the same quality ?

Comment: @monim well, in the designs it looks like the width does decrease a little but it crops it a certain amount to maintains quality.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your image with a `div`, and apply the following CSS to the wrapper:

```css
background: red;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
```

And for the image, apply this:

```css
height: 100%;
/* width: 1000px; */
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```